# Wrapping multiple element contents inside a paragraph

Tags: jquery, html

I have a an element that has multiple text and sub elements. I want to wrap them inside a paragraph

I know how to wrap single text elements inside their own p element, but I want to include any sub elements inside that p element if they separate the text.

Contents of element:

```
[text, h4, text, sub, text, sub, text, sub, text, br, br, br, center, br, br, br, text]
```

**Notice** the pattern text -> sub -> text -> sub... I want to wrap all these elements inside a single p element (sub "separates" the text, so it is considered part of it)

Code I currently have:

```
$(".back .main-text")
  .contents()
  .filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
  })
  .wrap("<p></p>")
  .end();
```

Initial html:

```html
<div class="text-center main-text">                      
<h4>Header</h4> Text with no p<sub>a</sub>, p<sub>b</sub>, and p<sub>c</sub> some other text here 
<br><br>
</div>
```

Expected output:

```html
<div class="text-center main-text">
<h4>Header</h4> <p>Text with no p<sub>a</sub>, p<sub>b</sub>, and p<sub>c</sub> some other text here</p> 
<br><br></div>
```

Actual output:

```html
<div class="text-center main-text"><p>                      
</p><h4>Header</h4><p> Text with no p</p><sub>a</sub><p>, p</p><sub>b</sub><p>, and p</p><sub>c</sub><p> some other text here 
</p></div>
```

Comment: Use `$(".main-text").contents().filter((i,v)=> v.nodeName != 'H4').wrapAll("<p></p>")`

Comment: Oh right! How didn't I think of that

Answer (score 0):

I came up with working code, although it is not pretty :)

```
contents = $('#main-card .back .main-text').contents();

main_parent = $('<div>');
save = $('<p>');

$.each(contents, function(i, content) {
  content = $(content).clone();
  if (content.prop("tagName") == "BR" || content.prop("tagName") == "CENTER" || $.trim(content.text()) != "") {
    tag = content.prop("tagName");
    if (typeof tag != "undefined" && tag != "SUB") {
      if ($.trim(save.html()) != "") {
        main_parent.append(save);
        save = $('<p>');
      }
      main_parent.append(content);
    } else {
      save.append(content);
    }
  }
})

if ($.trim(save.html()) != "") {
  main_parent.append(save);
}

$('#main-card .back .main-text').html(main_parent.html());
```

Feedback is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Not a general purpose solution. But if all of your source are like your initial text with different level of header, it should works fine.

```js
let d = document.querySelector('.main-text')
let c = d.innerHTML.split(/(?<=<\/h\d>)[''|\s+]/)

let r = `${c[0]}<p>${c[1]}</p>`
d.innerHTML = r
document.querySelector('output').value = r
```

```html
<div class="text-center main-text">                      
<h4>Header</h4> Text with no p<sub>a</sub>, p<sub>b</sub>, and p<sub>c</sub> some other text here 
<br><br>
</div>

<code>
<output></output>
</code>
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. I want to wrap text and sub elements inside a paragraph if they're together.

Comment: @OscarTorres I think you didn't understand the code. If you don't know vanilla js, I can't help.

Comment: @OscarTorres Though I wrote 5 lines code, but it only need 3 lines code to work, and you refuse to learn to read it.